# How using one element UI in multi getx controllers in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

I have a custom widget and this widget shared in multi pages but each page have it getx controller and. I need to put data inside the controllers come frome this widget
How can i solve this problem in flutter

I expect use  custom widget tget data from it like images for example
And put this data inside controller
But i have many controllers using this custom widget

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an instance of the control class and use it like the code below

for example it's your base class which has image data :

```
class A extends GetxController{
   File image = File('imagePath');
   File get getImage => image;
}
```

and now you would like to use it in side an other class which extends GetxController too
use code blow

```
class B extends GetxController{
final myController = Get.put(A());
myController.getImage();
}
```

This is an example of how to create instances of Getx classes